# Nova on Laradock raises bcadd exception

Tags: laravel, laradock, laravel-nova

I have a simple installation of Laravel with Laradock.
When I try to update a model, there is no problem.

However, when I install Nova and try to update some model (for example user name), I get the following error:

[image]

Looking at ajax call, I see the following error:

```
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "/var/www/vendor/moontoast/math/src/Moontoast/Math/BigNumber.php"
line: 506
message: "Call to undefined function Moontoast\Math\bcadd()"
```

I tried to set `PHP_WORKER_INSTALL_BCMATH` to `true` in `.env` and rebuild docker image, but it didn't help.

I also found this issue:
https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/25#issuecomment-432302285

But it didn't help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else experiencing this issue this is what solved it for me:
bin/bash into docker container and run

```
docker-php-ext-install bcmath
```

Then restart server. This helped for my case. I would expect analogical steps would work for Laradock.

Comment: I had to add this in addition to `apt install -y php7.2-bcmath` in laradock php-fpm